# I want to find multiple strings in a range and then for each find, fill the adjacent cell with a text

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am struggling with searching for a string in column and then filling a unique text in the adjacent cell.

For example, I have 3 names and I want to tweak them in adjacent cells as shown below (in reality I have around 20):

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name | Desired Format |
| 2 | Cat |  |
| 3 | Dog |  |
| 4 | Elephant |  |

The idea is to look for cat in range (A2:A4) and if found, input "17.Catiscool" in the adjacent cell and similarly look for Dog and if found, input "13.Dogisgood" in the adjacent cell to dog.

So far I have this code which just inputs "13.Dogisgood" in B3:

```vb
Sub To_be_renamed_as()
'Writing this to determine Correct Name format based on what we have from A3:A25
Dim oldRange As Range
Dim newRange As Range
Dim oldname As Object
Dim newname As String
'Our names start from A3 so I am going to start the range from A3
Set oldReportrange = Range("A3:A25")
Set newReportrange = Range("B3:B25")
For Each oldname In oldRange
    If oldname Like "dog" Then
    End If
    newname = ("13.dogisgood")
    oldname.Offset(0, 1) = newname 
Next oldname
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, it feels like a `Select ... Case` statement would work best.  I've edited your code to show one in use

```
Sub To_be_renamed_as()
'Writing this to determine Correct Name format based on what we have from A3:A25
Dim oldRange As Range
Dim newRange As Range
Dim oldname As Object
Dim newname As String
'Our names start from A3 so I am going to start the range from A3
Set oldReportrange = Range("A3:A25")
Set newReportrange = Range("B3:B25")
For Each oldname In oldRange
    Select Case ucase(oldname.value) 'Make the input value all uppercase for easier comparison
        case "DOG"
            newname = "13.dogisgood"
        case "CAT"
            newname = "17.Catiscool"
        case else
            newname = ""
    end select
    oldname.Offset(0, 1) = newname 
Next oldname
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of looking for a exact match, how do I look for few characters in the cell? For example, If I am looking for cat and the cell has "TomtheCAT" I still want to give new name as "17.Catiscool" .. 
Can I use something like a "*" instead of = to search for cat in TomtheCAT?
Thank you so much for helping me out Glenn!

Comment: @R.HarshavardhanReddy  If you are looking for a few specific characters then you would use the `InStr()` function.  This will return the numeric location of the the beginning of those specific characters in the text. If the number returned is anything other than 0, then the characters were found.  There are other ways to do this using excel's built-in "Find" function but I'm not familiar enough with those to give an explanation of how they work.

Comment: @GlennG You could still use `Select Case`; just need to rework it a bit.  eg. `s = UCase(w):    Select Case True:        Case s Like "*DOG*":  newname = "13.dogisgood"          :        Case s Like "*CAT*":            newname = "17.Catiscool":    End Select`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thank you for that bit of info, I'm not used to using `Like` statements outside of SQL, but the logic of it just makes sense seeing it

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code. It should be very fast, even for big ranges, using arrays:

```
Sub To_be_renamed_as()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, arrRep, El, arrEl, rng As Range, arrRng, i As Long

 Set sh = ActiveSheet   'use here the sheet you need
 arrRep = Split("cat|17.Catiscool,dog|13.Dogisgood,elephant|ElephantIsBig", ",") 'place here your conditions separated by "|"
 Set rng = sh.Range("A3:B25"): arrRng = rng.value   'set the range and put it in an array
 
 For Each El In arrRep                      'iterate between the arrRep elements
    arrEl = Split(El, "|")                  'split each element by "|"
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrRng)             'iterate between the arrRng rows
        If arrRng(i, 1) Like arrEl(0) Then arrRng(i, 2) = arrEl(1) 'when in the first column the search element is found
    Next i                                                         'the conditional string is passed in the second array column                                                         
 Next
 rng.value = arrRng  'Drop the processed array into the range, at once
End Sub
```

You can add in `arrRep` as many conditions (separated by "|") as you need...

Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: @R.Harsha vardhan Reddy Did you test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?